# Grouping by columns

Tags: excel, vba, grouping

I need help modifying this VBA to work on columns the exact same way it currently works on rows. I use this now in one sheet and it works perfect for me, but I need to adapt it. I found it here originally, but my guessing on how to modify it has not been successful. Thank you!

```
Sub TtlCoRecapGrouping()
Dim rng_cells As Range
    Dim rng_start As Range
    Dim rng_end As Range

    'set up some ranges, change rng_start to be appropriate
    Set rng_start = Range("A8")
    Set rng_end = rng_start.End(xlDown)
    Set rng_cells = Range(rng_start, rng_end)

    'clear previous outline
    Cells.ClearOutline

    'loop through level cells and group based on values below
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng_cells

        'get value of cell and start checking below it
        Dim row_off As Integer
        row_off = 1

        'loop ensures level is greater below and cells are within range
        Do While cell.Offset(row_off) > cell And cell.Offset(row_off).Row <= rng_end.Row
            row_off = row_off + 1
        Loop

        'do the grouping if there are more than 1 cells below
        If row_off > 1 Then
            Range(cell.Offset(1), cell.Offset(row_off - 1)).EntireRow.Group
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TtlCoRecapGrouping()

Dim rng_cells As Range
Dim rng_start As Range
Dim rng_end As Range
Dim i, j as integer

'set up some ranges, change rng_start to be appropriate
Set rng_start = Range("A8")
Set rng_end = rng_start.End(xlToRight)
Set rng_cells = Range(rng_start, rng_end)

'clear previous outline from columns
For i = 1 to Cells.Columns.Count
    If Columns(i).OutlineLevel > 1 Then
        For j = 2 to Columns(i).OutlineLevel
            Columns(i).Ungroup
        Next j
    End If
Next i

'loop through level cells and group based on values to the right
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rng_cells

    'get value of cell and start checking to the right of it
    Dim col_off As Integer
    col_off = 1

    'loop ensures level is greater to the right and cells are within range
    Do While cell.Offset(, col_off) > cell And cell.Offset(, col_off).Column <= rng_end.Column
        col_off = col_off + 1
    Loop

    'do the grouping if there are more than 1 cells to the right
    If col_off > 1 Then
        Range(cell.Offset(, 1), cell.Offset(, col_off - 1)).EntireColumn.Group
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply bigben! When I try to run it, I get a debug error on this line:  Do While cell.Offset(, col_off) > cell And cell.Offset(, col_off).Column <= rng_end.Column

Comment: Does your data start in cell A8 and go out to the right? (B8, C8, etc.)?

Comment: It actually starts in cell A1 and goes out to the right. Example: 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1 etc. I did change the range to start in A1 in the script.

Comment: What is the error message? And what is the "rng_end.Column" value? You should be able to hover over it and see after the debug error.

Comment: I pasted your code in again from scratch and ran it with cell A1 as the range start and it worked fine this time! Must've been something I did. Thank you so much for the answer. Works great!

Comment: One more ask - I do have a section of rows grouped manually in this workbook that I want to leave alone. The clearoutline clears all grouping before it runs. Can I target it to only clear the column grouping before it loops?

Comment: Revised the code to loop through columns instead of using "ClearOutline"